# CSS @viewport not working

Tags: html, css

I have a website that has a mobile viewport width of 480px. I can force this on mobile devices by simply adding the meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="480">
```

But this means that tablets also show this mobile version.

So following on from [this article on using the CSS @viewport instead](http://www.html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/) I have removed the old fashioned meta tags and replaced them with:

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
    @-ms-viewport {
        width: 480px;
    }
    @-o-viewport {
        width: 480px;
    }
    @viewport {
        width: 480px;
    }
}
```

But the website isn't being viewport zoomed at all on mobile devices. What gives? Is `@viewport` widely supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support across browsers for `@viewport` is less than great at the moment.

I would stick to using your meta for now.

Also you could use JS or Jquery to change the metatag depending on your sites width.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you.

@viewport inside of the CSS file is not supported for all browsers.

See [this table of compatibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport#Browser_compatibility) of the MDN.

Hope that'd be useful for you.